# Best way to download image (Likely to be changed later on) from Webservice to android

Tags: android

Good day,
I have an application that is divided into categories and each category is related to an image. The category and the image are likely to be changed randomly.
What would be the best way to deal with the image downloading :

1- At each opening of the application , using BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());

2- Creating a folder inside android, and downloading the images inside them for one time, then updating them each time there's a change.

3- Downloading the images and putting them inside a Database, then then updating them each time there's a change.

Or there's a better way ?

Regards.

Comment: Have a look at image loading libraries like picasso, or glide. Both support caching and lots of other things

Comment: Just use Glide!

Comment: I just implemented, the result is good, but my issue is, that the 1st time i open my activity there's a delay for downloading the images. How can i force my activity not to open before glide has finished downloading the images ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest either the 2nd or the 3rd option. Downloading the image every time your app starts is not a feasible option and would result in wastage of precious bandwidth.

You should use a listener to notify your app when an image changes and only then you should download the new image and upate it in your DB or local folder.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the url, use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

```
Picasso.with(context).load("yourUrlToImage").into(imageView);
```

It will deal with memory leaks and whatever.